# ffmpeg for windows: error when concatenating videos

Tags: ffmpeg

i have extracted a few clips from a video file of resolution 1920x816 called ca0.mp4...ca9.mp4 using the command

```
ffmpeg -i ./ca.mkv -ss 00:53:24 -t 00:01:30 ca0.mp4
```

Then i created a black video using

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=black:s=1920x816:r=24000/1001 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -ar 48000 -ac 2 -t 00:00:02 empty.mp4
```

now i want to concencate the clips with the black video between them. Therefore i created a file list.txt:

```
file 'ca0.mp4'
file 'empty.mp4'
file 'ca1.mp4'
file 'empty.mp4'
file 'ca2.mp4'
file 'empty.mp4'
file 'ca3.mp4'
file 'empty.mp4'
file 'ca4.mp4'
file 'empty.mp4'
file 'ca5.mp4'
file 'empty.mp4'
file 'ca6.mp4'
file 'empty.mp4'
file 'ca7.mp4'
file 'empty.mp4'
file 'ca8.mp4'
file 'empty.mp4'
file 'ca9.mp4'
```

and tried the command

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c:v qtrle -c:a copy ca.mp4
```

however, i get the following output:

```
ffmpeg version N-89940-gb1af0e23a3 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
  libavcodec     58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavformat    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.101 / 58.  0.101
  libavfilter     7. 11.101 /  7. 11.101
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001e2cd155900] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : 5.1
Input #0, concat, from 'list.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: -0.021333, bitrate: 1894 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x816 [SAR 1:1 DAR 40:17], 1500 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(ger): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 394 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> qtrle (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 000001e2cd213080] Could not find tag for codec qtrle in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
Conversion failed!
```

can anyone tell me, what i did wrong?

Comment: As the error says, qtrle `codec not currently supported in container`. Save to .mov

Answer (score 0):

As all files are already converted in .mp4 from .mkv

you may just need to copy the video codec too

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c:v copy -c:a copy ca.mp4
```

It will also speed up the process